# Zimbra 7.1.4 disaster recovery within the LDAP service

Tags: ldap, disaster-recovery, zimbra

We've a disaster in our Zimbra 7.1.4 server. The server is (was) running on a CentOS 6 box and it failed on the last friday.

After doing a lot of effort to make the machine boot once again Zimbra fails to start with a lot of errors. The first one was an error about the LDAP service:

```
Unable to determine enabled services. Cache is out of date or doesn't exist.
Unable to determine enabled services from ldap.
```

Doing a Google search it pointed out that the problem should be expired certificates. And at a first look it appeared to be the right answer, but it was not.

Editing the zmcontrol file I can see what the function is doing:

```
sub getEnabledServices {
unless (open (ZMPROV, "/opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov -l gs $localHostName 2>/dev/null |")) {
warn "Unable to determine enabled services from ldap.\n";

...

}
```

So the Zimbra startup script fails when running the `zmprov` program. Trying to run it manually returns a permission error:

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov -l gs localhost            
ERROR: service.FAILURE (system failure: ZimbraLdapContext) (cause:
javax.naming.AuthenticationException [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials])
```

At this point I don't know how to proceed. Since I'm not aware of any "credentials" for local ldap consults. I've run out of options.

I'm open to suggestions at this moment on how to handle this issue.

Thanks in advance,

PS: If there's a way to extract all the stored mail messages it will be a viable solution. Just export the mail and import to the new server. But I'm not sure how to do this, since the `zmmailboxd` isn't starting.

Comment: Is LDAP service in zimbra running?

Comment: No, it fails to start. EDIT: Actually it's running: zimbra   18762  0.0  0.4 228348 44024 ?        Ssl  18:54   0:00 /opt/zimbra/openldap/sbin/slapd -l LOCAL0 -u zimbra -h ldap://localhost:389/ ldapi:/// -F /opt/zimbra/data/ldap/config

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain the type of server failure (power, HDD crash, etc...), and all the other relevant details (HDD setup, raid controlers, etc)